# ASP.NET MVC customer portal User Junction Table

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Im building a management portal for a chain of restaurants. I am using ASP.NET MVC with EF Code First.

I want each user to, after login, only see the rescources that are connected to them. I want to put a junction table(many-to-many) between ApplicationUser and the Restaurant-class(model), since each user can have/work at many restaurants, and each restaurant can have many owners/workers.

How do you do this in EF Code first? The same way I did Restaurant --> Menue? Do you need to build a new DBContext for Applicationuser for this to work?

[image]

```
public class Restaurant
{

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Adress { get; set; }
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }

    //Connections
    public virtual ICollection<Menue> Menues { get; set; }
}

public class Menue
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }
    public DateTime ModifyDate { get; set; }

    //FK For RestaurantConnection
    public int RestaurantId { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For many to many configuration do like this

> Student class should have a collection navigation property for Course, and Course should have a collection navigation property for student

```
public class Student
{
    public Student() 
    {
        this.Courses = new HashSet<Course>();
    }

    public int StudentId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string StudentName { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Course> Courses { get; set; }
}

public class Course
{
    public Course()
    {
        this.Students = new HashSet<Student>();
    }

    public int CourseId { get; set; }
    public string CourseName { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Student> Students { get; set; }
}
```

In your DbContext add this configuration

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
modelBuilder.Entity<Student>()
            .HasMany<Course>(s => s.Courses)
            .WithMany(c => c.Students)
            .Map(cs =>
                    {
                        cs.MapLeftKey("StudentRefId");
                        cs.MapRightKey("CourseRefId");
                        cs.ToTable("StudentCourse");
                    });

}
```

For more information read this  article [Configure Many-to-Many relationship](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-many-to-many-relationship-in-code-first.aspx)